# Flexslider - Slide after Ajax add slide

Tags: jquery, flexslider

The Flexslider begins with four items already loaded and when I click the next navigation button, triggering a function with the "before" property to be load new publications/photos.
The problem is that while the content loads the flexslider tries to go to the next slide, but what I need is the flexslider wait for the ajax loading process and only after that do the animation to the next slide. Is this really possible?

The codes:

```
$('.section__slider-flex').flexslider({
        before: function(){
            clickToLoad()
        },
        animation: "slide",
        easing: "swing",
        slideshowSpeed: 3000,
        minItems: 2,
        maxItems: 4,
        itemWidth: 100
    });

var count = 2;
function clickToLoad(){
    $('a.flex-next').on({
        click: function(e) {
            var categoryID = $(this).closest('.section__slider-flex').find('.flex-viewport .slides .categoryID').val();
            loadArticle(count,categoryID);
            count++;
        }
    });
}
function loadArticle(pageNumber, categoryID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + "&loop_file=loop&id="+categoryID, 
        success: function(html){
            $('.section__slider-flex').data('flexslider').addSlide($(html));
        },
        error: function(html, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log( 'Something goes wrong: ' + textStatus + errorThrown );
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As I remember Flexslider requires the second parameter for `addSlide` which should be a position index of new slide.

Comment: I do not know if needed, because this content is being entered correctly at the end of everything.